# замена css свойству

Tags: css

С добавлением css свойства backdrop-filter: blur(20px), начинает тормозить сайт при скролле секции с данным свойством, как можно сделать размытие фона с помощью другого свойства.

Код:

```
.intro__card {
    width: 33.3333333333%;
    min-height: 433px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
    backdrop-filter: blur(20px);
    transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    padding: 101px 20px 90px;
    cursor: pointer;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    transition: .3s linear min-height;
}
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Может покажете присер кода чтобы понять как вам помочь?)

Comment: @Проста Miha, да, забыл вставить

Comment: Зачем такой сильный блюр? Обычно хватало около 2-4px.

Comment: @Oliver Patterson, в макете такой стоит)

Comment: Свойств на размытие фона в CSS больше нет. Да и текущее-то в тестовом режиме...